# Unable to locate package ros-hydro-cram-core

Tags: ros, installation, cram

[image: Rosanswers logo]

$ sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-cram-core
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-hydro-cram-core

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/138711/unable-to-locate-package-ros-hydro-cram-core/) by [ratneshmadaan](https://answers.ros.org/users/12636/ratneshmadaan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2014-03-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It appears to exist in public repositories: http://www.ros.org/debbuild/hydro.html

Can you install other ros-packages, for instances, ros-hydro-ros? If not, have you actually gone through the installation tutorial and added the repository, gotten the keys? Have you run apt-get update?

Also, what Ubuntu distribution are you on -- does it support Hydro?

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ratneshmadaan](https://answers.ros.org/users/12636/ratneshmadaan/) on 2014-03-12**:
I am on 12.04. Yeah, been using Hydro. Yes, I followed the tutorial.
It seems they just updated it. Have a look : http://cram-system.org/installation
the page now says to build from source.

**Comment by [gaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/9301/gaya/) on 2015-06-13**:
On 14.04 you build from source, on 12.04 you use the Debian. It's not a problem with the repo, it's your ROS setup.